# Alpha tesing with ES 3.0

Tags: opengl-es

With the core profile on desktop computers `GL_ALPHA_TEST` is not longer available so i wanted to remove them from my rendering engine. However on mobile platforms i'm not sure if this makes also sence, i read a couple of papers from graphic programers which state that disabling alpha testing improves the performance.

As far as i know alpha testing is a FFP thing. The concrete question i asked myself and now asking you is: Is there any performance difference when on mobile platforms when ignoring alpha testing and using shaders only.

Comment: Just because some people might ask: I've no actual device to test this on mobile devices. However i want to keep it compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alpha testing is not available in ES 2.0 and later. So it's not an option in ES 3.0.

The only OpenGL ES versions that supported `GL_ALPHA_TEST` were 1.0 and 1.1, and both of those are mostly considered obsolete these days.

You can easily replicate what the alpha test used to do in your fragment shader by checking the resulting alpha value, and calling `discard` if it does not meet the desired condition.

Comment: So basically this is just still inside because of compatibility reasons? Just wondering why then every "performance-paper" states that you should disable alpha testing. But ok.

Comment: You mean in desktop OpenGL? Yes, `GL_ALPHA_TEST` is still in the compatibility profile for compatibility reasons. It's not in ES 3.0 at all. Not in the spec document, not in the header file, or anywhere. It was in ES 1.x, but 2.0 was defined as a completely new API without any compatibility with 1.x.